# Finding Grade Entry Date based on change in Grade Value

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I have the following Dataset

| Date | ID | Grade | Grade Previous | Grade New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-05-08 | 0034 | 30 | 29 | 30 |
| 2006-10-23 | 0034 | 31 | 30 | 31 |
| 2006-09-10 | 0034 | 31 | 31 | 31 |
| 2020-12-08 | 0034 | 32 | 31 | 32 |
| 2003-01-22 | 0023 | 25 | 25 | 25 |
| 2023-01-18 | 0023 | F0 | 25 | F0 |
| 2009-09-08 | 0011 | 24 | 23 | 24 |
| 2012-04-09 | 0011 | 24 | 24 | 24 |
| 2023-05-04 | 0011 | 25 | 24 | 25 |

As you can see, Grade is basically the same exact as Grade New.

I want to be able to capture the date on which the Grade changes from previous to another by ID. So for example, when the grade for ID 0034 changes from 30 to 31 and from 31 to 32, I want to capture in a column and call it "Grade Entry Date". Similarly for ID 0023, and so on and so forth. In addition, I want to have another column that captures the latest Grade change date (Grade Last Change)

| Date | ID | Grade | Grade Entry Date | Grade Last change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-05-08 | 0034 | 30 | 2005-05-08 | NA |
| 2006-10-23 | 0034 | 31 | 2006-10-23 | NA |
| 2006-09-10 | 0034 | 31 | NA | NA |
| 2020-12-08 | 0034 | 32 | 2020-12-08 | 2020-12-08 |
| 2003-01-18 | 0023 | 25 | NA | NA |
| 2023-01-18 | 0023 | D0 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-18 |
| 2012-04-09 | 0011 | 24 | NA | NA |
| 2023-05-04 | 0011 | 25 | 2023-05-04 | 2023-05-04 |

Comment: Your expected results table is inconsistent. Why do ID 23 and and ID 11 have NA for Grade Entry Date on their first appearance in the table, but ID 34 doesn't? Why does Grade Last change for ID 34 not have an entry for 2006-10-23 even though the grade has changed? What is the difference between Grade Entry Date and Grade Last change, since apart from this inconsistency, they are just identical? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to fill the NA values of Grade Entry Date with the actual date of the grade entry?

Answer (score 0):

Simply ensure your data are sorted by ID and Date, then group by ID and grade. You can create a column of the first entry date by using `first(Date)`. Logically, the date of 'Grade Last Change' must be the same as the Grade entry date, so it seems pointless having it, but I suppose if you really need it you can copy it over. Note that there should not be NA values in your columns, since it is always possible to specify the grade entry date for any given row:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, Date) %>%
  group_by(ID, Grade) %>%
  mutate(`Grade Entry Date` = first(Date)) %>%
  mutate(`Grade Last Change` = `Grade Entry Date`) %>%
  select(-`Grade Previous`, -`Grade New`)%>%
  as.data.frame()
#>         Date   ID Grade Grade Entry Date Grade Last Change
#> 1 2009-09-07 0011    24       2009-09-07        2009-09-07
#> 2 2012-04-08 0011    24       2009-09-07        2009-09-07
#> 3 2023-05-03 0011    25       2023-05-03        2023-05-03
#> 4 2003-01-22 0023    25       2003-01-22        2003-01-22
#> 5 2023-01-18 0023    F0       2023-01-18        2023-01-18
#> 6 2005-05-07 0034    30       2005-05-07        2005-05-07
#> 7 2006-09-09 0034    31       2006-09-09        2006-09-09
#> 8 2006-10-22 0034    31       2006-09-09        2006-09-09
#> 9 2020-12-08 0034    32       2020-12-08        2020-12-08
```